# WFS version issue with DWITHIN CQL_FILTER in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql-filter, getfeature

If my WFS version is 1.0.0 as below:
    `service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typename=XXXX&outputFormat=json&srsname=EPSG:3857&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geometry,POINT(63.92449515625001 16.18202625967993),2.0185062969678143,meters)&`

I get the data properly, but if the WFS version is 1.1.0 the data is not coming properly.
    `service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typename=XXXX&outputFormat=json&srsname=EPSG:3857&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geometry,POINT(63.92449515625001 16.18202625967993),2.0185062969678143,meters)&`

The returned JSON does not have the data it has proper totalFeatures count only.

```
{
type: "FeatureCollection"
totalFeatures: 1
features: [0]
crs: null
}
```

Comment: Try `POINT(16.18202625967993 63.92449515625001)` with WFS 1.1.0 and above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely the axis flipping biting you, you should flip coordinates in WFS 1.1 and 2.0 filters:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/user/services/wfs/basics.html#axis-ordering

Comment: That document really needs some improvements. Now it is quite unclear when axis must be flipped and when not. Advice to have a look at the EPSG-registry would help http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326 -> flip, http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857 -> no flip, http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31467 ->flip

Comment: The documentation is open just like the software is, pull requests welcomed. Here is a quick guide on how to make a fix to the docs as a contributor: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/docguide/quickfix.html